# Send a message in socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a direct question: can use in **socket.io-client** a method like in **socket.io** `io.sockets.emit()` to broadcast messages?

Here is my code and what a want to do:

```
var ioc = require('socket.io-client');
var s = ioc.connect("http://localhost:8000/", {reconnection: true});

s.on('connect', function () {
    //...
}

//I want here out side of the <connect event> to send a message with  socket.io-client
```

Comment: i tried it and it work fine, that mine i can have access to it, the problem was from another place...thanx gays...

Comment: The answer is yes, if you make the reference available, it can be accessed from "other places". The only key that you must adhere to is that every exchange is asynchronous and you must treat it as such to avoid race conditions.

Comment: aa OK thanx for the info.my problem was from another place but thanxs for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks guys, the problem on from anothor place, I fixed it on my own like a man.

```js
var ioc = require('socket.io-client');
var s = ioc.connect("http://localhost:8000/", {reconnection: true});

s.on('connect', function () {
  ...........
}
s.emit('msg','message')
```